# PostSharp MulticastAttributeUsage MulticastTargets.Constructor option is deprecated

Tags: c#, visual-studio, postsharp

We use PostSharp on the project I've recently joined and I see compiler warning that MulticastTargets.Constructor option is obsolete for the following row:  `[MulticastAttributeUsage(MulticastTargets.Constructor | MulticastTargets.Method, AllowMultiple = true, TargetMemberAttributes = MulticastAttributes.NonAbstract)]`

The warning suggests replacing it with InstanceConstructor or StaticConstructor. What I'd like to do is to get rid of the warning, but also not change anything in the system.

I suppose that I need to replace the deprecated option with **both** newer options, i.e.: `MulticastTargets.StaticConstructor | MulticastTargets.InstanceConstructor`, but would like to be 100% sure that the behaviour stays the same. So, is such replacement correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.

It is defined exactly like that:

```
[Obsolete( "Use InstanceConstructor or StaticConstructor." )] 
Constructor = InstanceConstructor | StaticConstructor
```